# Full width <header> within a pagewrap container

Tags: css, html, position

I'm attempting to have the header element set at a full 100% width of the page.

For some reason, the header backdrop seems to be displaying a 100% width but it's floating left within the 'pagewrap' container.

[Live Example](http://blnr.org/testing)

HTML

```
    <body>

        <!-- start pagewrap -->
        <div id="pagewrap"> 

            <!-- start header -->
            <header>            
            </header>
            <!-- end header -->

        </div>
        <!-- end pagewrap -->   

    </body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#pagewrap {
    position: static;
    width: 900px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border-bottom: thin solid #C6D9F1;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the absolute positioning of the header element does not adjust to full screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left:0px;` on `<header>`...

Absolutely positioned elements are handled better when found in relatively positioned container.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. The header element needs to be 100% of the *page* not the container.

Comment: then take it out of the container

Comment: Yes, this only sets the width of the header to 100% of the parent container

Comment: I've updated - use `left:0px;` on the `header` and keep `position:static` on the container. However in my opinion taking the header out of the `#pagewrap` container is a better solution